# Generate polyline in paraview by loading data from .csv files

Tags: polyline, paraview

I am new to paraview and want to extract data along a polyline. This polyline however has 1000 points. If I use the polyline source in paraview, I need to add each point manually. I am thinking of adding the polyline points using a .csv. Want to know if it is possible.

One more way I was trying is to create a .vtk file of these points and load in paraview and then use 'plot over intersections' filter. But when I load the .vtk file I am not able to see the polyline in paraview. My .vtk file is shown below(Which also has the data of the .csv). Want to know if its the right approach.

```
# vtk DataFile Version 3.0
vtk output
ASCII
DATASET POLYDATA
POINTS 1001 float
0.0 0.035 0.0
2.5e-05 0.035 0.0
5e-05 0.035 0.0
7.5e-05 0.035 0.0
0.0001 0.035 0.0
...
....
....
0.024975 0.0332905856472015 0.0
0.025 0.033289979376219 0.0
```

Answer (score 0):

You should define cells in your file. Without cells, ParaView shows nothing.

In your case there should be one cell of type VTK_POLY_LINE.

In case, some documentation about VTK format: https://docs.vtk.org/en/latest/design_documents/IOLegacyInformationFormat.html